# Read a text file in windows directory outside eclipse project

Tags: java

My Java project is located at `C:\eclipse\workspace\cgw`

Is it possible to read a text file located on `C:\CGW\conexao\conexao.txt`

`File file = new File("C:\CGW\conexao\conexao.txt");`

Comment: Welcome on SO! See [ask] to improve the chance to get help here. But you should start by escaping those "\" or simply use "/" to be OS independent... Have you tried something ?

Comment: *"Is it possible to read a text file in `C:\CGW\conexao\conexao.txt`?"* **Yes.**

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file anywhere on your computer, here is an example using Java **BufferedReader**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample1 {

  private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {
        //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
          if (br != null) br.close();
          if (fr != null) fr.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

View [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) useful to read from files.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\CGW\conexao\conexao.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
 at principal.LerArquivo.main(LerArquivo.java:19)

and the file is there !

Comment: The answer from Carlos should work - can you paste your entire code that you have tried ? ( did you use the escape characters as indicated in Carlos answer ? )